# Lucene.Net fails at my host because it calls GetTempPath(). What's the work around?

Tags: asp.net, permissions, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net in an ASP.NET application on a shared host.   Got this stack trace shown below.  What's the work around?

[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.EnvironmentPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +59
   System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() +54
   Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory..cctor() +73

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer to my own question.   The solution was to modify Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory, by commenting out this unused line:

```
// Comments out by Corey Trager, Oct 2008 to workaround permission restrictions at shared host.  This is not used.
//        public static readonly System.String LOCK_DIR = SupportClass.AppSettings.Get("Lucene.Net.lockDir", System.IO.Path.GetTempPath());
```

There was one more security permission hurdle after that, and here's that workaround too.   I don't understand why one way of getting the names of files in a directory would be blocked, and another way not blocked.

```
    public override System.String[] List()
    {

/* Changes by Corey Trager, Oct 2008, to workaround permission restrictions at shared host */
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory.FullName);
            System.IO.FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            string[] list = new string[files.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                list[i] = files[i].Name;
            }
            return list;
/* end of changes */

//            System.String[] files = SupportClass.FileSupport.GetLuceneIndexFiles(directory.FullName, IndexFileNameFilter.GetFilter());
//            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
//            {
//                System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(files[i]);
//                files[i] = fi.Name;
//            }
//            return files;
        }
```