# ASP.NET MVC - Full text search on shared hosting

Tags: full-text-search, shared-hosting, asp.net-mvc-3

We are developing a Q&A site for a client with very limited budget. Site will be developed in ASP.NET MVC 3, and client will have an option to switch between SQL Express and SQL CE.

We would like to have some full text search functionality but don't know what would be the best for this scenario. So far we've seen SOLR and Lucene.NET, but the most likely site will be hosted on some shared hosting so we have to take that into account.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO `bin` deployed [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) is the way to go. You just might need to [modify it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194795/lucene-net-fails-at-my-host-because-it-calls-gettemppath-whats-the-work-ar) so that it stores the index in a folder you have write access.